# Fill rows of an (10000,2) array using another array's values as indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab, data-science

I have an array, idnl, that contains non-consecutive numbers in order from 0-10000

```
u = rng.integers(0, 100, size = N)/100.0
temp = (np.cumsum(priors))
thresholds = [temp[0], temp[1],1]
indl = (np.argwhere(u <= thresholds[l]))
Nl = np.size(indl)
```

Array x is [10000, 2] filled with zeros.

```
x = np.zeros((n,N)).transpose()
```

**I want to generate a normal distribution of random numbers and copy each ordered pair to the rows in x, that are indexed by indl.**
The matlab code would be `x(:,indl) = mvrnd(...etc..)`

```
x[indl,:] = rng.multivariate_normal(meanVectors[l,:], covMatrices[l,:,:], Nl)
```

x should look like this -

```
[0,0
0,0
0.53, 0.98
0,0
0.46, 0.56
0.87, 0.23
.
.
.]
```

but I keep getting errors like this:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (5106,2)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1,5106,10000)
```

I've been at this for hoooours....pls help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at numpy.reshape>

I would use

```
np.reshape(x, (-1:2))
```

this will create a 2d list.

```
[[0,0], [0,0], [0.53, 0.98] ....]
```

you can then use a for loop to loop through the list.

```
for arr_element in x:
    print(arr_element[0], arr_element[1])
```